# Python Selenium - open multiple tabs in loop

Tags: python, selenium, scripting

Im trying to make a python script using selenium that will open multiple chrome tabs.
So I made a loop like below but it stops on 9 windows when I replace "url" with actual url which points to video. Do you have any ideas what can be wrong here? Is it like it wants to open 100 tabs with video but PC can't handle it or can it be optimized?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
number = 0
while number < 100:
  driver.execute_script('''window.open("url","_blank");''')
  driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[number])
  number = number + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried such code and it worked properly. I did not count the opened tabs, but they were definitely much more than 10 and the program finished with no errors.
This is the code I used (like your, but with more details):

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")

webdriver_service = Service('C:\webdrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=options)
url = 'https://www.some_rela_url'
driver.get(url)
number = 0
for number in range(100):
  driver.execute_script('''window.open("url","_blank");''')
  driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[number])
```

Comment: You can use `window` instead of executing script, I think it's better. Check my answer for more details about it.

Comment: I validated the approach the OP asked about.

Comment: Ah. Still, if there's a better way to do it, I think it's better to tell him.  
Or at least I would like to know it if I were him.

Comment: That's right. I agree. But, again. This should be said as improvement

Comment: So, what I want to do is replace "url" here driver.execute_script('''window.open("url","_blank");''') with actual url. That makes it stop on 9 tabs

Comment: You didn't mention that in the question... I'll try this later.

Answer (score 0):

Like this it works and opens 100 tabs

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common import window

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
for _ in range(100):
    driver.switch_to.new_window(window.WindowTypes.TAB)
```